# Comparing similar logistic regression models, where an independent event does and does not happen

Tags: regression, logistic, propensity-scores

Apologies if this is a silly question, but I've built a logistic regression model for predicting propensity to buy on a website, given that a visitor does or does not visit certain pages.

I would like to look at the probability of purchasing if the visitor does or does not visit a certain webpage to see how important it is to steer a visitor towards that page.

I've done a bit of research and come across propensity score matching, is that the appropriate method or are there other suggestions as to how I can appropriately compare outcomes where a visitor does or does not perform a certain action?

Thanks